# Infinite Loop or Early terminating do while loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop, do-while

I have been fighting with this program for awhile now.  It has started to compile correctly, but when I run it as it is, it says "Your bill is __" infinitely.  When I change the initial response value it refuses to run.  I'm at a lose as to how to fix it.

```
/* Savannah Moore
   CSCI 1301
    2/11/2013
    Internet Package Code: Code determines customer's final pricing. */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class internet{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      double hours, price;
      int internet;
      String response, check="Yes";


      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); /* This sections questions the user as to which package they have bought. */
       System.out.println("Our internet packages include:");
        System.out.println("Package 1: For $9.95 per month, 10 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Package 2: For $13.95 per month, 20 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Package 3: For $19.95 per month, unlimited access is provided.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your package number:");
       internet=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your total hours used:");
       hours=kb.nextDouble();   
        response = "Yes";

while(check.compareToIgnoreCase(response)== 0)
  {
      switch (internet)
      {
      case 1: 
              {  if (hours > 10)
                       price = (hours-10)*2 + 9.95; /* This adds the additional hours to the user's price at the current overage rate. */
                    else    
                        price = 9.95;
                }
              System.out.println("Your bill is $" +price);  
               break; 
      case 2: 
              {  if (hours > 20)
                       price = (hours-20) + 13.95;
                    else    
                        price = 13.95;
                }
              System.out.println("Your bill is $" +price);  
               break;        
     case 3:System.out.println("Your bill is $19.95");  
                break; 
      default: System.out.println("This package choice is invalid.");

      System.out.println("Would you like to compare your price with that of another package? Yes or No"); /* This gives the user the ability to stop the loop. */
      response=kb.nextLine();
      response=kb.nextLine();   
     }
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you for using us as your internet service provider.  Have a nice day!");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop  goes infinite because the chances for the user to change the response to 'No' are inside the case statement.  Therefore, when you `break;` out of the case statement, you immediately jump back into the 'while' check, and because *response* and *check* are both still 'Yes', it does it all again.

Just put those statements after the `default:` case in the case statement and it should work.

In other words, change:

```
   ...
   default: System.out.println("This package choice is invalid.");

   System.out.println("Would you like to compare your price with that of another package? 
       Yes or No"); /* This gives the user the ability to stop the loop. */
   response=kb.nextLine();
   response=kb.nextLine();   
  }
}
```

to:

```
     ...
     default: System.out.println("This package choice is invalid.");
   }
   System.out.println("Would you like to compare your price with that of another package? 
        Yes or No"); /* This gives the user the ability to stop the loop. */
   response=kb.nextLine();
   response=kb.nextLine();   
}
```

I'm not sure why you're doing `response=kb.nextLine();` twice.

Comment: I have the response=kb.nextLine(); line twice because the program will not pause for the user input with out it for some reason.  But when I did what you said about changing the } it did not return to the while statement at the beginning.

Comment: Never mind I realize that I needed to move my reading of user input.  Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program
{
    /**
     * This is the main entry point for the application
     */
  public static void main(String[] args){
      double hours, price;
      int internet;
      String response, check="Yes";


        response = "Yes";

while(check.compareToIgnoreCase(response)== 0)
  {

      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); /* This sections questions the user as to which package they have bought. */
       System.out.println("Our internet packages include:");
        System.out.println("Package 1: For $9.95 per month, 10 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Package 2: For $13.95 per month, 20 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Package 3: For $19.95 per month, unlimited access is provided.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your package number:");
       internet=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your total hours used:");
       hours=kb.nextDouble();   
      switch (internet)
      {
      case 1: 
              {  if (hours > 10)
                       price = (hours-10)*2 + 9.95; /* This adds the additional hours to the user's price at the current overage rate. */
                    else    
                        price = 9.95;
                }
              System.out.println("Your bill is $" +price);  
               break; 
      case 2: 
              {  if (hours > 20)
                       price = (hours-20) + 13.95;
                    else    
                        price = 13.95;
                }
              System.out.println("Your bill is $" +price);  
               break;        
     case 3:System.out.println("Your bill is $19.95");  
                break; 
      default: System.out.println("This package choice is invalid.");
      }
      System.out.println("Would you like to compare your price with that of another package? Yes or No"); /* This gives the user the ability to stop the loop. */
      response=kb.nextLine();
      response=kb.nextLine();   

    }

    System.out.println("Thank you for using us as your internet service provider.  Have a nice day!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I will need the response to be false if the user input's no.

Comment: I have edited my answer....if issue is resolved mark the answer as resolved for future reference.